# Pass a single argument as dots in tidyeval

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am trying to wrap `dplyr::filter` within a function where when there is more than one `filter` condition, then they are passed as a vector or list. See this minimal example:

```
filter_wrap <- function(x, filter_args) {
  filter_args_enquos <- rlang::enquos(filter_args)
  dplyr::filter(x, !!!filter_args_enquos)
}
```

When there is a single condition I can make it work:

```
data(iris)
message("Single condition works:")
expected <- dplyr::filter(iris, Sepal.Length > 5)
obtained <- filter_wrap(iris, filter_args = Sepal.Length > 5)
stopifnot(identical(expected, obtained))
```

When I try to pass more than one condition I get a problem. I was expecting that the `!!!` operator in the `dplyr::filter` call would splice my arguments but given the error message I guess I am understanding it wrong.

```
message("Multiple conditions fail:")
expected <- dplyr::filter(iris, Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5)
obtained <- filter_wrap(iris, c(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
# Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 150, not 300
# Called from: filter_impl(.data, quo)
stopifnot(identical(expected, obtained))
```

Using a list does change the error message:

```
obtained <- filter_wrap(iris, list(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
# Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
#  Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
# Called from: filter_impl(.data, quo)
```

I don't want to use `...` as my function will have other arguments and I may want to use dots for something else.

How can I expand my `filter_args` argument when passing it to `dplyr::filter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically your problem is that when you call `enquos()` on the single parameter, you are also quoting the `list()` call (which is a single call). So basically you are creating

```
filter_args_enquos <- quo(list(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
```

and when you call

```
dplyr::filter(iris, !!!filter_args_enquos)
```

that's the same as

```
dplyr::filter(iris, list(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
```

which isn't valid dplyr syntax. The `!!!` needs to work on a proper list-like object, not an un-evaluated call to a list, note that this would work

```
filter_args_enquos <- list(quo(Sepal.Length > 5), quo(Petal.Length > 5))
dplyr::filter(iris, !!!filter_args_enquos)
```

because here we are actually evaluating the list, and only quoting the things inside the list. This is basically the type of object created by enquos when using ...

```
filter_wrap <- function(x, ...) {
  filter_args_enquos <- rlang::enquos(...)
  dplyr::filter(x, !!!filter_args_enquos)
}
filter_wrap(iris, Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5)
```

The `enquos()` function expects multiple parameters, not just a single list. That's why it's meant to be used with `...` because that will expand to multiple parameters. If you want to possibly pass in a list, you can write a helper function that can look for this special case and expand the quosure properly. For example

```
expand_list_quos <- function(x) {
  expr <- rlang::quo_get_expr(x)
  if (expr[[1]]==as.name("list")) {
    expr[[1]] <- as.name("quos")
    return(rlang::eval_tidy(expr, env = rlang::quo_get_env(x)))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}
```

Then you can use it with

```
filter_wrap <- function(x, filter_args) {
  filter_args <- expand_list_quos(rlang::enquo(filter_args))
  dplyr::filter(x, !!!filter_args)
}
```

and both of these will work

```
filter_wrap(iris, Petal.Length > 5)
filter_wrap(iris, list(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
```

but this is not really the way this `enquo` stuff is "meant" to be used. The `...` method is much more idiomatic. Or calling `quos()` explicitly if you need more control

```
filter_wrap <- function(x, filter_args) {
  dplyr::filter(x, !!!filter_args)
}
filter_wrap(iris, quo(Petal.Length > 5))
filter_wrap(iris, quos(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! I get it now! I will consider your suggestion about not being really the way `enquo` is meant to be used and use `quos` instead...

In any case, can it be that the `rlang::eval_tidy(expr)` call should actually be `rlang::eval_tidy(expr, env = rlang::quo_get_env(x))` so it is evaluated in the environment from `x`?

Comment: Sure. If your actual use case was using variables from places other than the columns of the data.frame, you would want to capture the right environment.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood it right, here is a quick'n'dirty solution:
The problem is / was that by combining your logic queries combined by c which results in a vector as long as x * n of comparisons.

```
filter_wrap <- function(x, filter_args) {
     filter_args_enquos <- rlang::enquos(filter_args)
     LogVec <- rowwise(x) %>% mutate(LogVec = all(!!!filter_args_enquos)) %>%             
     pull(LogVec)
     dplyr::filter(x, LogVec)
}

expected <- dplyr::filter(iris, Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5)
obtained <- filter_wrap(iris, c(Sepal.Length > 5, Petal.Length > 5))    

stopifnot(identical(expected, obtained))
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to understand how to make it work with rlang, but your quick'n'dirty solution solves my problem :-)